# Checking for Pareto Distribution

Tags: distributions, pareto-distribution

I am trying to test the following statement:

" Zipf's law is an observation about how often different words are used. Zipf's law predicts that in a body of text, the distribution of word frequencies is roughly pareto. "

I am reading a text file with approx $100,000$ words. Did a word count, generated a CDF out of it and then plotted it. (Using python)

The output was as follows:

[image]

It seems like a **pareto** distribution, I also read that for testing for a distribution the **CCDF** i.e the Complementary CDF which is (1-CDF) helps, So I did the same, calculated the CCDF and plotted it using 'log' as 'xscale' and 'yscale'. So, ideally it should be a straight line but the output is as follows:

[image]

Is this okay ? Since the distribution is 'roughly' pareto ?

Comment: Please explain how you managed to estimate a CCDF down to $10^{-13}$ when you have only $10^6$ (or maybe $10^5$?) observations.  That seems like a gross extrapolation--but this region of apparent extrapolation dominates your plot!

Comment: I calculated 'cdf' as a dictionary in python which maps a key to a particular value, so the cdf function is like this :   cdf['married']= 0.9999800151883492 , cdf['platforms']=0.9999999999998924 and so on.

Now for calculating CCDF, for each key in that dictionary, I subtracted the corresponding value from '1' , i.e CCDF['platforms'] => 1-cdf['platforms'] = > 1-0.9999999999998924 and so on.. @whuber

Comment: Also, CCDF is plotted with 'xscale' and 'yscale' as 'log'. @whuber

Comment: The problem is that those values are impossible values for a CCDF for such a small dataset.  I wasn't asking how you did the arithmetic--I was wondering what *justifies* values that appear to be outlandish.  They call into question the validity of all your graphics.

Comment: Is 1,00,000 meant to be one million but missing a 0, or are you indicating a lakh ? If the former, please edit to fix the typo, if the latter, please note that most readers outside India will be completely unfamiliar with the notation (and so again please edit -- the more widely understood notation would be one of 100,000 or 100 000, or 100.000 in some parts)

Comment: Note that zeta or Zipf distributions are not actually Pareto distributions.

Answer (score 2):

Zipf is all about Power Laws, so any plots should show a straight line linear relationship between $y=\log_e(f_w)$ vs $x=L_w$, where $f_w$ is word frequency and $L_w$ is word length.  If you want to determine if $f_w$ is Pareto distributed, then just perform empirical cumulative distribution fitting (ECDF) using values in the first plot.  You would need to compare the Pareto to other distributions using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov or Anderson-Darling tests vs the Power, Gumbel, distributions to determine which fits bests.

Overall, Zipf is a power law and this can be tested for intermittency using quantum chromodynamics, QCD (based on factorial moments).  Pareto fits is an entirely different question based on ECDF.

Comment: So looking at the first plot only, can I say "Yes, this is roughly pareto. " ?

Comment: No, distributions have parameters, so you should overlay cdfs of several Pareto distributions.  However, ECDF is the process of fitting to find the optimal distribution which matches your cdf.